# Why "target_folder.upload_file(sFilename, file_content).execute_query()" is not overwriting the existing file in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, python

I have kept some files in a Share Point folder. I need to run a python script to update the files daily.
Code -

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File

def writeData(dfResult,relUsagePath,sFilename):
   try:
        target_folder = baseCtx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(f"Shared 
        Documents/{relUsagePath}")
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        dfResult.to_csv(buffer, index=False,encoding='utf-8',lineterminator='\n')
        buffer.seek(0)
        file_content = buffer.read()
        target_folder.upload_file(sFilename, file_content).execute_query()
   except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

This function **can upload a new file in the same SharePoint location** but it **cannot overwriting an existing file in the same SharePoint location**.

Surprisingly it does not even throw any exception. The code runs smoothly and at the end the files which are expected to get overwritten remain as is.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

The `upload_file` method in the `Office365-REST-Python-Client` library creates a new file if one does not exist. However, it doesn’t overwrite an existing file.

Try adding the `.encode()` function to the results of the `.to_csv()` function. This will properly convert the resulting CSV to a binary string: https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/issues/490

Replace:
`file_content = buffer.read()` with `file_content = buffer.getvalue().encode()`

Test and let me know if that works for you.